# relating to $L_{p}$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ be a measurable function. 
For each $1\le p<+\infty$, setting $$\|f\|_{p}:=\left(\int\limits_{X}|f|^{p}\, \mathrm{d}\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \text{(not necessary finite)}.$$
 The question is that $$\|f\|_{p}\to \|f\|_{p_{0}}\, \text{ as }\, p\to p_{0}?$$